# how to count number of rows in html table generated dynamically?

Tags: php

Can anyone please help me to count the number of rows in html table that is dynamically generated using javascript?If anyone can help in this let me know as I have trying to insert data of dynamically generated rows into database

My js code :

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
 var count=1;
    function addRow(tableID) {
        /*if(empty(index))
        {
        var index = 0;

        }
        else
        {
        index++;
        alert(index);
        document.getElementById('cat').name = 'cat'+index;
        }*/

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var count =  rowCount-1;
        alert(rowCount);

        var selectOFCat = $("#"+tableID).find('tr:eq(0)').find('.cat').get(0);
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }

        $(table).find("tr:eq("+rowCount+")").find('.cat').attr("id","cat"+rowCount);

    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }


  function changeSelection(value){

  var length = document.getElementById("ind").options.length;

  if(value == "All"){
  for(var i = 1;i<length;i++)
    document.getElementById("ind").options[i].selected = "selected";

  document.getElementById("ind").options[0].selected = "";
  }
```

}

```
</SCRIPT>
```

My php code:

```
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5>Add your Products</h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                           <tr><td>
                           <INPUT id="add_row" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" class="btn btn-danger" name="add_row" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" class="btn btn-danger" />
<tr>
<td bgcolor="red">
<TABLE width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" >

                            <tr><td width="2%">::</td><td style="width:213px;padding:5px;">Type</td><td class="srcinfo_head">Product</td><td  class="srcinfo_head">Specification</td><td class="srcinfo_head_op">Option</td><td class="srcinfo_head_src">Source</td><td  class="srcinfo_head">Frequency</td><td  class="srcinfo_head">Quantity</td><td  class="srcinfo_head">Unit</td>
                            </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<TABLE id="dataTable" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" style="border:#cccccc; border-width:3px; border-style:solid">

    <TR valign="top">
        <TD width="2%"><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" style="margin:5px;"/></TD>
        <TD class="srcinfo">
    <select  id="cat" class="cat" name="data[cat][]" size="10px" class="srcinfo_type" style ="height:77px !important;">
    <option value="">--Select a Category--
    <?= $options ?>
</select> 
        </TD>

        <TD width="15%"><?php echo tep_draw_input_field('data[productname][]','','class="srcinfo"'); ?></TD>
        <td width="15%">
        <?php echo tep_draw_textarea_field('data[specification][]', 'soft', 10,3, $HTTP_POST_VARS['specification'],'class="srcinfo"'); ?>
        </td>
        <td width="10%"><div class="srcinfo_op">
        <?php echo tep_draw_checkbox_field('data[option][]','purchase', false).'&nbsp;Purchase';
              echo tep_draw_checkbox_field('data[option][]','sell', false).'&nbsp;Sell';            ?>
        </div>

        </td>
        <td width="15%">

        <?php   $source_array = array();
                $source_array[0] = array('id' => 'All', 'text' => 'All India');
                $source_array[1] = array('id' => 'AP', 'text' => 'Andhra Pradesh');
                $source_array[2] = array('id' => 'ARP', 'text' => 'Arunachal Pradesh');
                $source_array[3] = array('id' => 'ASM', 'text' => 'Assam');
                $source_array[4] = array('id' => 'BHR', 'text' => 'Bihar');
                $source_array[5] = array('id' => 'DL', 'text' => 'Delhi');

                echo tep_draw_pull_down_menu('data[source][]', $source_array,'','class="srcinfo_source" multiple onchange="changeSelection(this.value)" id="ind"'); ?> 
        </td>
        <td width="10%">
        <?php   $frequency_array = array();
                $frequency_array[0] = array('id' => 'Yr', 'text' => 'Yearly');
                $frequency_array[1] = array('id' => 'mnth', 'text' => 'Monthly');


                echo tep_draw_pull_down_menu('data[freq][]', $frequency_array,'','class="srcinfo" style="margin-top:50px;"'); ?> 
        </td>
        <td width="8%">
        <?php echo tep_draw_input_field('data[qty][]','','class="srcinfo" style="margin-top:50px;"'); ?>

        </td>
        <td width="10%">
        <?php   $unit_array = array();
                $unit_array[0] = array('id' => 'kg', 'text' => 'kilogram');
                $unit_array[1] = array('id' => 'gr', 'text' => 'gram');
                $unit_array[2] = array('id' => 'mg', 'text' => 'milligram');


                echo tep_draw_pull_down_menu('data[unit][]', $unit_array,'','class="srcinfo" style="margin-top:50px;"'); ?> 
        </td>
    </TR>

</TABLE>       
</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>
                            <?php echo tep_draw_button(IMAGE_BUTTON_PRODINFO, 'person', null, 'primary',array( 'params' => 'name="add_pro" class="btn btn-danger" ')); ?>
                            </td></tr>
                        </table>
                        <?php

                    if(isset($_POST['add_pro']))
                        {
                        foreach($html->find('dataTable') as $table){ 
                         $all_trs = $table->find('tr');
                         $count = count($all_trs);
                         echo $count;
                         exit;
                        }
                        $src = $_POST['source'];
                        $products_source = implode(",", $src);
                        $opt = $_POST['option'];
                        $products_options = implode(",", $opt);
                        $products_array = array(
                          'products_quantity' => $products_quantity,
                          'products_date_added' => 'now()',
                          'products_source' => $products_source,
                          'products_frequency'  => $products_frequency,
                          'products_options' => $products_options,
                          'products_unit' => $products_unit,
                          'customers_id' => $customer_id
                          );

                        tep_db_perform(TABLE_PRODUCTS, $products_array);
                            $products_desc_array = array(
                          'products_name' => $products_name,
                          'products_description' => $products_description
                          );

                        tep_db_perform(TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION, $products_desc_array);
                        $prod_id = tep_db_insert_id();
                        $category_id_array = array('products_id' => $prod_id,
                                                    'categories_id' => $category_type_id);
                        tep_db_perform(TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES, $category_id_array);
                        $update_stage = tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS . " set customers_stage='5' where customers_id = '" . $customer_id. "'");
                        tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_REGISTRATION_6, '', 'SSL'));
                        }

                    ?>
                    </form>
```

I want to insert the values of the rows in a form which is generated dynamically.

Comment: state your question clearly, with some appropriate code you tried, and add proper tag to your question...!

Comment: Why is this tagged "php"?

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: is it being generated using jquery? or do you have jquery in the same script?

Comment: are you posting the actual table rows (html) or just data in the rows (form elements)?

Comment: no code, no description -1

Comment: if you have jquery you can do this by `$(".TABLE_CLASS_OR_ID tr").length`; check this http://jsfiddle.net/G3Dtu/

Comment: do you want to do with php or with javascript?

Comment: I want to count rows using php as I want to insert the values of dynamically generated rows into the database.

Comment: see my answer it will help you to work out with php

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with jQuery, Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dt = $(".TABLE_CLASS tr").length;
    alert(dt);
});
```

check it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/G3Dtu/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use any of the following alternatives.

1. [simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
2. [PHPquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)
3. [snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/)

These are the `PHP` scripts which will count the table rows as well as you can work it as a `jQuery` functions.

/*EDITED*/

I am giving you a example for this with the help of simple html dom parser.

```
 include("../simplehtml/simple_html_dom.php");
 require('../phpQuery/phpQuery/phpQuery.php');

$html = file_get_html("http://".$_GET['siteName']);
$es = $html->find('table tr');
```

hope this helps.
PS. I did not test this example if you find difficulties then please let me know.

Comment: foreach($html->find('dataTable') as $table){ 
$all_trs = $table->find('tr');
 $count = count($all_trs);
echo $count;}                                                             This I edded where 'dataTable' is my table name.But it is showing a fatal error.                                                               Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Comment: have you included class file?

Comment: can you just elaborate please?

Comment: yes sure which one did you use?

Comment: I am updating my answer

Comment: Thanks Rajat :) I have included both the files.But what does file_get_html("http://".$_GET['siteName']) indicate?

Comment: your page url which have the html you can use it also when you are going to save your detail.

Comment: actually no need of this.Found the solution .Just need to count the number of values in any filename array.Thanks for spending your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in PHP, you need a (web) client side language. Here's the native JS version:

```
var rowCount = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
```

if you have more than 1 table on the page, you'll need to change the document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0] part to get the right table.

Bear in mind this will get all the rows in the table, including any header rows.

Comment: why he can't work this one with php. there are many scripts which helps to count as well as add and remove class same as the javascript.

Comment: I put the answer in before the edit with the code samples, so assumed it was a table made from an XHR request, as the question had 'html table that is dynamically generated'. Even so, if you're adding and deleting rows on the browser and want the new row count, you'll need to do that in JS.